# HL7-FHIR handle CRUD and history

Tags: mongodb, hl7-fhir

Learning FHIR, I have this basic CRUD question, but I still need your help.

In order to keep history, are the Create, Update and Delete basically inserting a new record with special flag/status?

Just brainstorming,
For update, should I insert a new record and update the previous record as 'not active'?
For delete, should I update the previous record as 'deleted';

In order to keep history, should I wrap the resources as a sub-component in my document. For example,

{ 
   _id: Object_id,
   _history: history_record,
   _metadata: other_metadata,
   fhir_resource: fhir_resource
}

Is the above wrapper idea a common practice?
Do you have any article and sample implementation about this?

Best regards,
Autorun

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this about persistence layer behind a FHIR API or are you talking about the client side that communicates to a FHIR server?

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I am trying to implement the backend persistent layer behind a FHIR API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you're pretty much spot on. The spec mentions this kind of design in a couple pf places, for example [in delete](http://build.fhir.org/http.html#delete):

"For servers that maintain a version history, the delete interaction does not remove a resource's version history. From a version history respect, deleting a resource is the equivalent of creating a special kind of history entry that has no content and is marked as deleted."

Comment: Thanks Vadi. I will follow this guideline and try to implement it. I think I will have questions soo.